How to make your wordpress plugin dependent on other plugins like Advanced Woo Search does?
My WordPress plugin may only be activated when other plugins are activated. WooCommerce for example. It also has to display an admin notice into in plugin row. Does anyone know how to deal with this?
I tried using plugin_row_meta, but that only shows when the plugin is activated, it also doesn't work with admin notices and the plugin can still be activated. I've been seeking on the internet for a while, but I just can't find how this could be made. I also don't have a lot of experience with WordPress.

This feature is relatively new and can be utilized by adding a new header comment to your plugin - Requires Plugins.
You can learn more about how to use it in the official WordPress.org announcement.

Thank you for your answer. That might explain why it was so hard to find on the internet. I think this new feature is really handy.
